# How close to Rust can C++ become in terms of memory safety?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, rust

Someone said to me that we can achieve Rust's memory safety in C++ using modern features.

I understand that if people didn't use raw pointers and used, for example, `std::vector<T>` to replace `T*`, in cases like `T = uint8_t`, then we'd have array bound safety for pointers, pretty much like slices in Rust.

Also we can use smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>` to pass that vector around without copying and have RAAI preventing memory leaks. Still, the vector provides us raw access to the data, but let's suppose someone is careful with that and only accesses the vector through `operator[]`.

Preventing memory leaks and invalid memory addresses are the main feature in Rust. I don't know what other features it has, so I'm asking how it compares to a carefully written C++ code in terms of safety.

Also, I presume that there's an overhead in `operator[]` because the bound verification would be in C++ code, while Rust does the same verification in low level. So if we'd write a kernel, I guess relying on the overhead of C++'s `operator[]` would be a problem. However, C++ can also have inline assembly code. So couldn't this overhead be inserted into assembly in order to have the same performance as in Rust?

Also, is there noticeable overhead in Rust's bound checking vs C raw pointer access without bound checking?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> to pass that vector around without copying and have RAAI preventing memory leaks.` if you don’t need shared ownership for that vector you wouldn’t use `shared_ptr` to pass it around without copying it you would either use references or move semantics.

Comment: There is a definite difference between Rust and C++: Rust _supports_ (i.e. forces) error-free life-time/ownership management. C++ _allows_ error-free life-time/ownership management. For the latter, it's still easy to shoot in your own foot. "_allows_" is not enough to prevent human mistakes (which unfortunately happen naturally). (I ignore the fact that Rust provides as well back-doors aka. unmanaged code.)

Comment: `operator[]` calls can be inlined, the compiler should really get rid of them most of the time. "Also, is there noticeable overhead in Rust's bound checking vs C raw pointer access without bound checking?" Yes (profiling is the only way to be sure for certain cases, but in general yes, bounds checking individual array access will add up and affect performance). Take this last part with a grain of salt as I've limited experience with rust, but from what I gather it can be as unsafe as c++, it just makes you work to break it in a spectacular fashion with things like `unsafe`.

Comment: To solve the problem of bounds checking, I tend to write assertions in C++ which only compile on debug builds. So I get bounds checking on Debug builds and hope that it'll work just as well on Release. Always using unsigned types for array access also helps.

Comment: In most implementations `operator[]` does no bounds checking, you need to use `at`

Comment: You can't implement Rusts's safe borrowing in C++.

Comment: Rust has compiler checked equivalent to move. In C++ only you being careful saves you from reusing a moved object.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy TBF C++'s move semantics are different than Rust's, so the moved-from object is in some sort of valid but undefined state (which specific objects can define). OTOH that says nothing about UBs e.g. a moved-from `unique_ptr` is essentially a null pointer, and UB to deref unless you've `reset()` it to a new valid value.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your main question "How close to Rust can C++ become in terms of memory safety?"

> but let's suppose someone is careful with that

There is the thing. The compiler will be that careful someone for the Rust sources.

The other thing you're missing is sharing data between threads. And again the rustc will help you (and all your interns and juniors) to keep out of a lot of possible issues.

It is still possible to be careful enough to write error free code in C++. But you have to waste a lot of your mind power for the things which may be checked by compiler in Rust. Of course it may change in new versions of C++.

Comment: I mean, you can have the same safety writing raw machine code if you're willing to devote the brain power to it—the point, like you say, is that it's really easy to make mistakes and having the compiler enforce certain guarantees is hugely beneficial.  I'd go so far as to say that this comes down to the semantics of what is meant by the word "safety" and, applying Rust's definition, C++ is undoubtedly unsafe.

Comment: "It is still possible to be careful enough to write error free code in C++. " history shows that this is a completely theoretical possibility on any non-trivial codebase

Comment: @Masklinn -  In my experience, the biggest problem with getting code right is understanding what it is supposed to do (i.e. the requirement) not the coding itself.   No amount of support from a programming language helps with that one.   That's why a lot of formal software development approaches (standardized or proprietary) put a lot of focus on the requirements elicitation, as well as on coding technique.   Unfortunately, there are too many programmers who jump straight past the requirements elicitation, and dive straight into their keyboard.